# Retrieving Data

Tags: http, coldfusion

I need to do an HTTP call to this page for every bike (one) and wheels seq (many) combination in the database:

```
http://web_address/index.cfm?fuseaction=bike=444444&wheels_seq=1111
```

and get the form values from the database.

After this, submit this form programmatically with the form values by firing the Send button on the page.

What are your suggestions to complete this task?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this your site or someone elses site you are scraping?

Answer (score 1):

General advice: don't do chatty services. For ex. if you need to fill data in a form, bring all the data in one call and format it locally for rendering, instead of increasing client and DB roundtrips. Of course, you have to make a tradeoff between minimizing roundtrips by designing chunky calls and usability e.g. responsiveness.

Another useful point that is usually forgotten: use paging on the user side. Instead of displaying 100 bikes at once, display by, say, chunks of 20 and accumulate choices as the user travel from page to travel. This is very dependant on your app, but you get the idea.